# How to Convert UTC Datetime to EST Time zone?

Tags: looker-studio

I am creating dashboards using Google Data Studio, and need to change Time zones:

- My date column is currently in `UTC`;
- I need to convert it to `EST`.

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved using the new Date and Time functions (introduced in the [17 Sep 2020 Update](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6311467#sep-17-2020)).

### 0) [Upgrade the Date Field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63926419/12892553)

Ensure that the **Date** field has been upgraded to to the newer Date field type.

Added a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

### 1) `EST`

The [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below looks at the [`DATETIME_DIFF`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9698749) between `CURRENT_DATETIME("UTC")` and `CURRENT_DATETIME("EST")` and then subtracts the difference with the DateTime field (titled `Field` in this report):

```
PARSE_DATETIME(
    "%s", 
    CAST(CAST(FORMAT_DATETIME("%s", Field)AS NUMBER) - DATETIME_DIFF(CURRENT_DATETIME("UTC"), CURRENT_DATETIME("EST"), SECOND)AS TEXT ))
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/e136cf14-dc73-4262-8fac-51f9357ee489) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

to_char(timezone('America/Toronto', timezone('UTC', table.created_at)), 'YYYYMMDDHH') AS created_at_datehour

Comment: It seems like you suggest to use database function. Is there option to specifie timezone in report or datasource?