# How to Calculate Duration in Hours Using Google Data Studio

Tags: time, looker-studio

I'm trying to get the duration in hours using data stored in Google sheets using the following fields and display the data in Google Data Studio.

[image]

[image]

I was able to get the results I wanted in Google sheets using `=(H2-I2)*1440`. However, I want the managed the calulation using Google Data Studio. I tired using `CAST(EndTime AS NUMBER ) - CAST(StartTime AS NUMBER )` in Google Data Studio but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 0) Summary

The below looks at 2 questions:

1. **Updated Question** (**DATETIME_DIFF**): Find the difference between the two time fields, `NewStartTime` and `NewEndTime` and also incorporate a `Date` field;
2. **Original Question** (**TIME_DIFF**): Looks for the difference between 2 Time fields, `StatTime` and `EndTime`.

## 1) Update (17 Sep 2020 Dates & Time Update)

Updated the Answer with the solution using the [Updated Date Time Functions](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6311467?hl=en#sep-17-2020) which incorporates the [`PARSE_DATETIME`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9739558) and [`DATETIME_DIFF`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9698749) functions:

### 1.1) Upgrade the Date Field

Upgrade the `Date` field to the newer Date field type and ensure that the `NewStartTime` and `NewEndTime` fields are set to **Text**.

Added a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

### 1.2) `DATETIME_DIFF`

Copy-paste the [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below to create a value in seconds that shows the difference between the two fields:

```
DATETIME_DIFF(PARSE_DATETIME("%Y/%m/%d%I:%M:%S %p",CONCAT(Date,NewEndTime)), PARSE_DATETIME("%Y/%m/%d%I:%M:%S %p",CONCAT(Date,NewStartTime)), SECOND)
```

### 1.3) Type (`DATETIME_DIFF`)

```
Number > Duration (Sec.)
```

Added a [New Page to the Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/44aa7e42-bf58-4535-9f0e-224d282af34b/page/RtQgB) and a GIF to demonstrate:

[image]

## 2) Original Post

It can be achieved using the 3 steps below:

### 2.1) Type (HH:MM Fields)

By default, the fields should be detected as **Text** fields, if not ensure that they are set to Text fields at the Data Source, such that it looks like:

[image]

### 2.2) `Time_DIFF`

Copy-paste the [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below to create a value in seconds that shows the difference between the two fields:

```
((CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(EndTime,"^(\\d+):")AS NUMBER)*60*60) + (CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(EndTime,"^\\d+:(\\d+)")AS NUMBER)*60) + NARY_MAX(CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(EndTime,".*(PM)$","43200")AS NUMBER),0)) -
((CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(StatTime,"^(\\d+):")AS NUMBER)*60*60) + (CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(StatTime,"^\\d+:(\\d+)")AS NUMBER)*60) + NARY_MAX(CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(StatTime,".*(PM)$","43200")AS NUMBER),0))
```

### 2.3) Type (`Time_DIFF`)

```
Numeric > Duration (Sec.)
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/44aa7e42-bf58-4535-9f0e-224d282af34b) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]